# What does := mean in VBA

Tags: vba, colon-equals

This might be a simple question but I'm searching online for the answer and can't seem to find it.

With the use of the code below as an example, what do these symbols mean.  Symbol 1       `:=""`  Symbol 2       `:=_`

```
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
```

Comment: I have tried to find but not succeed in that.  It looks like assignation in  Pascal.  Are you sure it is vba?

Comment: Just recorded a macro to print and the code for it in vba includes the line of code I used here as the example. So I'm positive it's vba

Comment: Yeahhh  I believe! I was just surprised and I couldn't find anything in the original documentation.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so called "Named argument". Meaning you can pass arguments to PrintOut in any order you like, as long as you name them on the left side of ":=" operator.

Alternatively you would need to provide all the arguments in the exact order  specified here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840681.aspx

More on named arguments in VBA here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx